# How to understand the return values when it comes to using import random, .radiant(), or .choice()?

Tags: python, python-3.x

So for a HW assignment, we're making a Yahtzee game. At least part of it. For preparation, our professors gave us a few questions to understand the main point of the assignment.

1) The following documentation is provided for one function:

def roll_dice():
''' rolls 5 dice, and returns a list of frequencies of each possible value
for example, element [3] of the return value is how many 3's appeared
'''

GIven this documentation, and the fact that the dice are six-sided cubes with the numbers 1,2,3,4,5,6 to choose from, which of these would be a correct return value from this function?

Ans: [0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 2, 0]

2) Given the same documentation as the previous question, which of these would represent a dice roll with 4 2's?

Ans:  [0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 1]

3) Which of the following would represent a case where all five dice rolled the same value, considering the documentation in the first question?

Ans: [0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0]

4) In the game of Yahtzee, a full house is defined to a situation where three of the dice have the same number, and the other two dice equal each other (but different from the first three).

Which of these would represent a full house, given the documentation from the first question?

Ans: [0, 2, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0]

I don't understand how to interpret these types of questions. For 1) the range would be from (0,2)? Hence giving you the random amount of times for getting it? Or would we be using choices() with weights instead? For the second one, what does the '4' represent? The third question is along the same lines.

Comment: Something's off here - some of the lists have 7 elements instead of 6. A 6 sided die can only return values 1-6, but the wording of the first question implies that the frequency of the number 3 is stored in element[3] - so what's being stored in element[0]? Are we considering a value of 0 being rolled as a possible value?

Comment: Yeah, that confused me as well. It was an online quiz so these are the actual given answers once you submit it.

Answer (score 0):

The numbers in brackets represent the frequency of a specific dice roll, corresponding to the numbers on the dice in order from 1 through 6.

The listed answer for 2) would correspond to a dice roll of 4 3's, because the 4 is in the 3rd position in the array.